# Asp.Net MVC form, with unknown parameters for Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a questionnaire mvc webapp, and i cant figure out how to pass an unknown number of arguments to the controller from the form.

My form is something like:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
<div id="Content">
    <% foreach (var group in ViewData.Model.QuestionGroups)
       { %>
    <div class="Group">
        <%=group.Description %>
        <% foreach (var question in group.Questions)
           {%>
        <div class="Question">
            <div class="QuestionTitle">
                <%=question.Title %>
            </div>
                <%=Html.Hidden("Id", question.ID) %>
            <div class="QuestionText">
                <%switch (question.TypeAsEnum)
                  {
                      case QuestionTypeEnum.Text:%>
                <%=Html.TextBox("somename") %>
                <% break;
                      case QuestionTypeEnum.Number:%>
                <%=Html.TextBox("somename") %>
                <% break;
                      case QuestionTypeEnum.PhoneNumber:%>
                <%=Html.TextBox("somename")%>
                <% break;
                      case QuestionTypeEnum.Email:%>
                <%=Html.TextBox("somename")%>
                <% break;
                      case QuestionTypeEnum.Date:%>
                <%=Html.TextBox("somename")%>
                <% break;
                      case QuestionTypeEnum.YesNo:%>
                <%=Html.RadioButton("somename", true)%>
                <%=Html.RadioButton("somename", false)%>
                <% break;
                      case QuestionTypeEnum.Alternative:%>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("somename", question.Answers)%>
                <% break;
                  }%>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
<div id="submittButton">
    <%=Html.SubmitButton()%></div>
<% } %>
```

Now what i need in my controller is List< ResponseAnswer >, 
where ResponseAnswer has the properties:

string questionID,
string AnswerText,
bool AnswerBool,
number AnswerNumber,
...

So how can i pass an unknown number of items containing questionID, AnswerType and Answer to the controller.
In webforms i solved this by rendering the form with repeaters instead of foreach, and then iterating through the question repeater checking the control id, each repeater item containing a hidden questionid element and a input with id=AnswerType.
But this will seriously break Separation of concern in mvc?

So is there any way of getting my controller to accept List< ResultAnswer > and somehow build this list without breaking soc, and if not, how do i pass the entire formresult back to the controller so i can do the iteration of the form data there instead of in the view.

Comment: You answer might be here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49304732/7149454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Garry's answer will work (and hence, up voted). However, you can model bind directly to a list, and I think it's a bit more elegant. [There are instructions in this blog post.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: The link is not working. Can you provide a code sample? It's the suggested way of answering in SO.

Answer (score 10):

You can add an argument to your action like

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form)
```

Then the `form` parameter will contain all the data from the posted form. From that you can do what you want.

You could probably implement a binder that could map to ResponseAnswers but I have no experience of doing that so I'll leave that to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify gary's answer, you can then easily walk through all fields of the form like this

```
foreach (string s in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    if (s.Contains("number"))
        number = int.Parse ((Request.Form[s]));

    //do something
}
```