# Razor Pages : Inheritance of a model to add fields during creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

These entities are fictitious equivalent of what I am trying to accomplish (which is more complex in real).

I need extra fields to appear in form only when creating the Article (SendToSubscribers field), and these aren't part of the entity itself.

```
public class Article {
    public string Title { get; set }
}

public class ArticleCreateForm : Article {
    public bool SendToSubscribers { get; set; }
}
```

In the cshtml to create/update there is :

```
@model Article
...
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Id))
{
    <admin-input asp-for="SendToSubscribers" />
```

Unfortunately, this is the error I get :

> 'Article' does not contain a definition for 'SendToSubscribers' and no accessible extension method 'SendToSubscribers' accepting a first argument of type 'Article' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Sorry if approach not good at all, I am coming from a PHP background.

I guess it's not the good solution so how can I make this correct ? Thanks.

Comment: no need to create another model just to hide the title field, when razor page renders into html form, only the fields defined in the razor page will be rendered.

Comment: In this case it won't work because the field is SendToSubscribers

Comment: The c# do not lend themselves to this.

Comment: @dctremblay Please check formcollection object to pass dynamic entities in a class

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you don't like it, but usually, the cleanest approach is creating different models for different views and keep those models different from your persistence models.

In this approach you should `ArticleCreateModel` which only have those properties which are needed for creating an article, including the `SendToSubscribers`. But it should not have the `Id` property because `Id` is not needed in view. So this should be model:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
public class ArticleCreateModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool SendToSubscribers { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `Create` action of `ArticleContoller`, receive `ArticleCreateModel` and then to persist data, you can create an `Article` and persist in the storage and depending to the value of `SendToSubscribers` you will decide to send the article to subscribers as well:

```
public ActionResult Create(ArticleCreateModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid())
    {
        ArticleBustinessLogic.Create(ArticleCreateModel model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

        // Or simply
        // var article = new Article();
        // article.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        // article.Title = model.Title();
        // ArticleRepository.Create(article);
        // ArticleSubcription.NotifySubscribers(article);
        // return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

In this approach, the model of the `View` should be `ArticleCreateModel` and you don't need any `if` statement:

```
@model ArticleCreateModel

...    

<input asp-for="Title" />
<admin-input asp-for="SendToSubscribers" />

...
```

**Note**

As I mentioned before, it's not the only solution, but it's one of the cleanest solutions. In the first glance you may say it adds an overhead in development because of different views and different models, but in long run, it is worth to use this approach because it makes the view code, controller code and business logic code cleaner without if statements and make the application easier and cleaner to test and maintain. You may also want to use an object to object mappers like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to map view models to persistence models easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has an approach, that is connected to design patterns.

Create a container class, that will occupy both of the models:

```
public class MainArticleModel{
    public Article article {get; set;}
    public ArticleCreateForm articleCreateForm {get; set;}
}
```

Then you will be able to use it:

```
@model MainArticleModel
...
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Id))
{
    <admin-input asp-for="SendToSubscribers" />
```

This way, both of the models will be contained by a single view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Form Collection** to add additional parameters in view, which is not available in model

**View**

```
@model Article
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("submit", "Home", new { id = "form1" }, FormMethod.Post))
{

 <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
 <input type="text" name="Title" value="est" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="SendToSubscribers" value="true" />
 <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
     <input type="button" id="btnLogOn" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
 </div>
}
```

C#

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public void submit(Article a, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            var data = a as ArticleCreateForm;
            bool SendToSubscribers = Convert.ToBoolean(formCollection["SendToSubscribers"]);

        }
    }
```

[image]

**Code**

[image]

You can also convert formcollection to class object

[how to convert formcollection to model in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364751/how-to-convert-formcollection-to-model-in-)

Answer (score 0):

```
@{var m = (ArticleCreateForm)Model;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Id))
{
    <admin-input asp-for="m.SendToSubscribers" /> }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Transfer Objects

Models :

```
    public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
    public class ArticleDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool SendToSubscribers { get; set; }
}
```

Controller : i use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Title,SendToSubscribers")] ArticleDto articleDto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var article =_mapper.Map<Article>(articleDto); // AutoMapper here
        //Here you can use articleDto.SendToSubscribers as you want
        await _articleRepository.AddAsync(article);//Example
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(article);
}
```

View :

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ArticleDto

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>ArticleDto</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="SendToSubscribers" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SendToSubscribers)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```